# Ошибка при конвертации данных из Object [ ] к Double[ ]

Tags: java

Выскакивает ошибка при конвертации данных из Object [ ] к Double[ ]:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

```
static Object [] riznicyaKupivli = new Object[28];
Double [] vsiRiznici = new Double[riznicyaKupivli.length];
    System.arraycopy(riznicyaKupivli, 0, vsiRiznici, 0, riznicyaKupivli.length);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vsiRiznici));
```

Данные которые хранятся в Object []:

```
28.070
31.727
0.376
35.174
27.117
7.063
0.243
20.200
19.700
4.160
3.290
3.020
1.193
0.092
28,27
32,07
7,43
0,43
36,16
28,21
19,87
4,30
21,50
3,37
0,10
1,24
3,08
0,25
```

Это я добавляю елементы из двух таблиц JTable в массив обьектов

```
 for(int i = 0; i<14; i++){
    riznicyaKupivli[i] =  dtm.getValueAt(i, 1);

    }

    for(int j = 14; j<riznicyaKupivli.length;j++){
        riznicyaKupivli[j]= dtm2.getValueAt(k, 1);
        k++;
    }
```

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: У меня Ваш код работает.

Comment: Может добавьте больше кода

Comment: @ВалерійГрузицький добавил,посмотрите

Comment: Запятые уберите и называйте переменные нп тоанслитерацией а согласно конверсии

Comment: @GenCloud не понимаю что вы имеет виду, где запятые убрать, киньте пример того то вы говорите пожалуйста

Comment: @CR7, что такое `dtm`? И какое изначальное значение `k`?

Answer (score 0):

Значения возвращаемые методом `getValueAt()` в JTable почти всегда являются строками, а так как метод `arraycopy` не производит никаких конвертаций, вы получаете `ArrayStoreException` при попытке заполнить массив Double-ов строками.

Ниже я привел пример как нужно в вашем случае сделать:

```
Object [] objarr = new Object[1]; // В вашем случае 'riznicyaKupivli'
Double [] darr = new Double[1]; // 'vsiRiznici'
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel(); // Получаем модель JTable

objarr[0] = Double.parseDouble((String)dtm.getValueAt(0, 0)); // И теперь мы
            // сначала приводим значение из таблицы (Object) в строке (String),
            // а затем в ней парсим (Double), цикл for я опустил для наглядности

System.arraycopy(objarr, 0, darr, 0, objarr.length); // Копируем массив
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(darr)); // Получаем значения в массиве 'darr'
```

Только удостоверьтесь что в таблице и правда числа, иначе будет брошено исключение `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: нет не помогло, не понимаю что не так

Comment: @CR7 Можете тогда добавить в вопрос максимсльно полный код, желательно который можно сразу запустить?

Comment: ну воопше смотрите, перед мной стоит задание, вычетать разницу между колонками первой таблицы и второй таблицы. Сначало я подумал, что данные из конкретной колонки в таблице1 и таблице2 нужно добавить в массив и там уже делать вычетание. И эту разницу занести в таблицу3. Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что данные из таблиц считывает в массив Обьектов, но я подумал что потом можно перевести их в массив Double.Но выскакивает ошибка. Может вы подскажите как по другому можно посчитать разницу между колонками из двух таблиц?